# MySQL Adding A Yes/No Column and Filtering

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to add yes/no column to my query.  Here's my scenario:

Schema

```
Table_A    Table_B
-------    -------
uid         uid
color       name
```

Sample Data

```
Table_A       Table_B
uid    color   uid     name
1      red      1      Joe 
1      blue     1      Joe
```

Query

```
SELECT table_a.color,table_b.name
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE table_a.color LIKE 'red'
```

This works as expected, however, I want to add a column named 'blue' and if Joe has the blue color as well as the red color, add a 'Y' to the column otherwise add a 'N'.

Expected Results

```
uid    color    blue
1      red      Y
```

Comment: Do you want to show all the records with extra blue column

Comment: No, I would like those to be excluded from output results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query to get result

```
        SELECT A.uid,A.color,case when cnt=2 then 'Y' else 'N'  end as blue
        FROM tableA as A
        LEFT JOIN (select uid as id,count(distinct color)as cnt from  tableA
        WHERE lower(color)  in ('blue', 'red') group by uid)  as B ON A.uid = B.id 
        WHERE A.color='red'
```

Comment: 'select uid as id,count(distinct color)as cnt from  tableB' - color does not exist in table_b in my example.  Should this be table_a?

Comment: Yeah that is tableA only, sorry for that

Comment: Thank you this method was what I was looking for.  Works as expected.